# "willingness to pay" for meaning of affordability?

Tags: american-english

I'm looking for research paper(or wikipedia page, whatever) about willingness to pay for something in general. Since I noticed the significant difference of "willingness for paying" between countries, for example, Japan and the US, with consideration of average disposable income.

Accounting to wikipedia, "willingness to pay" is described as:

> willingness to accept (WTA) is the minimum monetary amount that а person is willing to accept to sell a good or service

So, the meaning of this term is generally used for a good or service. Not as whole or general sense.
In this case, what English word can I use to describe the "willingness to pay" instead?

Comment: You ask about willingness to *pay* but then give a definition for willingness to *accept*, which is the opposite side of the transaction.

Comment: Are you looking for a term that would be commonly used by experts involved in finance, or by the man in the street? 'How much people are prepared to pay for something' is probably the normal way to describe this to the man on the Clapham omnibus, but it's hardly a fixed expression.

Comment: *How much people are prepared to pay for something* can also be colloquially/idiomatically expressed as *What the market will bear/stand*.

Comment: @StephenS There are two Wikipedia pages, one for each for "willing to pay (WTP)" and "willing to accept (WTA)" each of which has a link to the other. They are very similar so I think the OP has got a bit confused when copying.

Comment: For this question to be answerable, it needs to be better explained why *willingness to pay* is not good enough; why does it need a substitute? Also, it is confusing that the title refers to affordability (which is a related, but not the same concept), and the body of the question then does not say anything about affordability.